# Jekyll treating custom variable in included file as filename

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I've got a custom variable that I'm passing into my include file which is strangely being treated as the filename. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

I'm including my component with:

```html
{% include_relative includes/form/components/modal.html for="purpose" %}
```

And the contents of the `includes/form/components/modal.html` is:

```html
<div class="modal-custom modal-custom-white" data-modal-custom="{% include.for %}" data-modal-requires-update-button>
  <div class="modal-custom-background bg-white"></div>
  <div class="modal-custom-content p-3">

    {% if include.title %}
      <h5 class="font-weight-normal text-dark mb-3">{% include.title %}</h5>
    {% else %}
      <h5 class="font-weight-normal text-dark mb-3"><strong>Tap</strong> to choose:</h5>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Modal content here -->
    {% if include.content %}
      {% include.content %}
    {% endif %}

  </div>
  <button type="button" class="modal-custom-close is-large bg-light" onclick="toggleModal('purpose', 'close-retain');diposeExpandedToggler('purpose', true)"></button>
</div>
```

I'm running the latest version of Jekyll, version 4.2.0 and if I remove the `for` then everything works just fine. I've tried:

- renaming the variable
- cleaning the cache
- formatting the variable in different ways such as: `for=purpose` and `for="purpose"`

I've created something similar in another component and everything works fine there, but the error I'm getting here is:

> Liquid Exception: Could not locate the included file '.for' in any of ["/Users/USER/Sites/MY-PROJECT/src/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source. in icicle.html

Which is strange. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to use the output tags `{{ include.for }}` rather than the non-output ones `{% include.for %}`. This is the case for `include.title` and `include.content` here as well.

You should pass a variable without the quotes, otherwise you'll be passing the string literal `"purpose"` instead of the value that the `purpose` variable holds.

Although it might work anyway, I'd avoid using `for` as a key if possible since it's the for loop keyword used in Liquid.